# Symfony Query Builder syntax

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do a query builder, but I dont know how to start as the query is a bit complex.

The query in SQL is like that:

```
SELECT email FROM AdminUsers WHERE id = (
    SELECT u_id FROM user_groups WHERE group_id = 'id_from_group_table'
);
```

I'm querying 3 tables, as I have a table Users, table Groups, and a third table containing the relations between them with user_id and group_id for each row.

How can I achieve that with a Query Builder or DQL?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you build your entities? You have to use ManyToMany relationships on the User entity and Group entity. Than you can query these entities relatively easy

User entity

```
/**
 * @var Group
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_group",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $groups;
```

Group entity

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="groups")
 */
private $users;
```

Dont forget to initialize the $users and $groups var in the constructor

```
public function __construct
{
     $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Now you can query these entities

In a controller

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->FindByGroup($yourGroupId);
```

or if you want to use the QueryBuilder

```
$q = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:User')
     ->createQueryBuilder('user')
     ->select('user.email')
     ->innerJoin('user.group', 'group')
     ->where('group.id = ?1')
     ->setParameter(1, $yourGroupId)
```

and the documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm right now with another issue, I'll check your answer and the one below to see if it works. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work (not actually tested)

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.email FROM AdminUsers u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT g.u_id FROM user_groups g WHERE g.group_id = ?1 AND u.id = g.u_id)')->setParameter(1, 321); //where 321 the id you are looking for

$emails = $query->getResult();
```

Documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html
More documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

A small tutorial on subqueries:
http://www.philipphoffmann.de/blog/2012/08/29/a-bulletproof-pattern-for-creating-doctrine-subqueries-of-any-complexity/

**Edit**
Note the '?1' in the query body and the 'setParameter()' method at the end, this is how you should pass parameters to any query, doesn't matter if built with Query builder or DQL or even SQL. Do it always as it protects you from SQL-injections!

Comment: A question about it, how can I use the XXX as e.g. $group->getId()? ->setParameter('group_id', $group->getId()); ??

Comment: Sorry about that, it's supposed to be just whatever id you are looking for, of curse it makes sense to take that as a parameter, i'll edit the answer to add that change :)

Comment: Your answer is right, but as I was asking about Query Builder, the other answer is the right one. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You asked about QB or DQL. This is DQL. Both approaches work and are appropriate for slightly different kind of situations tough :)